# apt-get tries to remove all xserver-xorg packages when I install web browser

Tags: linux, browser, debian, aptitude

When I try to install uzbl, a minimalistic web browser with apt-get, apt tries to remove **a lot** of packages that can't possibly have any relations to the uzbl package - since it's only a web browser.

```
[ ~/downloads ] % sudo apt-get install uzbl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bluez-gnome libswfdec-0.6-90 libpopt-dev libplist1 evolution-common mesa-utils libgnomekbd2 libtracker-client-0.8-0 gnome-utils-common libepc-ui-1.0-1 libepc-ui-1.0-2 libtalloc1 libcdio10 geoclue libglib-perl libwildmidi1
  ekiga python-opengl liborc-0.4-0 python-gst0.10 libzbar0 libio-compress-zlib-perl gcalctool libcompress-raw-zlib-perl libarchive1 libpth20 python-gnome2 gnome-nettool libflite1 gnome-media libepc-1.0-1 libepc-1.0-2
  libgtk-vnc-1.0-0 python-pexpect nautilus libgksu1.2-0 python-notify xfonts-scalable baobab libtelepathy-glib0 libsensors3 usbmuxd gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly python-beaker genisoimage gnome-settings-daemon obex-data-server
  djvulibre-desktop librdf0 libsrtp0 libbrasero-media0 brasero-common libsoundtouch1c2 libgda3-common gucharmap zenity libgksuui1.0-1 libdiscid0 gnome-games hplip-cups cheese upower libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libgnome-media0
  app-install-data gnome-power-manager gnome-cards-data check gnome-screensaver libgtksourceview1.0-0 rhythmbox libburn4 w3c-dtd-xhtml gnome-screenshot python-gdata alacarte gedit gnome-menus python-gtksourceview2
  gnome-session-common gtk2-engines-pixbuf libtdb1 system-config-printer dvd+rw-tools apache2.2-bin libio-compress-base-perl cheese-common xserver-common python-gtkglext1 libdca0 libapm1 epiphany-extensions
  python-sqlalchemy libpt-1.10.10-plugins-alsa libupower-glib1 gnome-themes update-notifier-common libtrackerclient0 metacity-common seahorse libggzmod4 libgnome2-perl libxml-twig-perl libtotem-plparser10 libslv2-9
  libusb-1.0-0 libtotem-plparser17 python-pyorbit totem-common libaprutil1-ldap python-gconf libass4 gvfs-bin vinagre swfdec-gnome libedata-cal1.2-6 libdevkit-power-gobject1 libpt-1.10.10 libsysfs-dev libdirectfb-extra
  gnome-media-common seahorse-plugins nautilus-data librasqal2 bluez libgnome-menu2 libgeoclue0 libgalago3 system-tools-backends libpciaccess0 liblqr-1-0 libgnome-bluetooth7 gconf-defaults-service libdirectfb-dev
  libpolkit-gtk-1-0 libeel2-data python-gtkmozembed xkb-data python-gtkhtml2 xfonts-75dpi python-beautifulsoup libgnomekbd-common p7zip gedit-common gnome-utils gnome-themes-extras libopal3.6.8 libdmx1 libschroedinger-1.0-0
  libdirectfb-1.2-9 libgssdp-1.0-2 libcryptui0 libgdu-gtk0 finger gdm-themes libnet-dbus-perl arj python-webkit libenca0 gnome-about gnome-volume-manager libexempi3 libcdio-cdda0 gtk2-engines libgnomeprint2.2-data
  libgtksourceview2.0-common python-imaging libkpathsea4 libgnomekbdui2 eog gdm xfonts-base libgtksourceview2.0-0 libslab0 gnome-dictionary capplets-data libgnome2-vfs-perl gnome-disk-utility python-glade2 gnome-backgrounds
  python-eggtrayicon python-sip4 obexd-client python-xdg gnome-spell gnome-search-tool libvpx0 python-vte libggz2 libgtk2-perl gnome-session-bin python-xapian libjpeg62-dev libgme0 libgmime-2.4-2 libunique-1.0-0
  python-feedparser wodim libgtksourceview-common vino gnome-system-monitor libcanberra-gtk0 libimobiledevice1 python-gnupginterface libbluetooth3 gnome-games-data media-player-info telepathy-mission-control-5
  libapache2-mod-dnssd rcs python2.6-dev libeel2-2.20 libclutter-gtk-0.10-0 libmagickcore3 libopal-2.2 totem-gstreamer libgnome-window-settings1 libdvdread4 xfonts-100dpi cdrdao libgdata7 libgnomevfs2-bin libdrm-radeon1
  libchamplain-0.4-0 keyboard-configuration libchamplain-gtk-0.4-0 libepc-common libkate1 gstreamer0.10-nice libcdaudio1 libmimic0 libmozjs1d libmpeg3-dev libcap-ng0 libusbmuxd1 python-bugbuddy libpt2.6.7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you try to install a package that pulls in a bunch of dependencies, one of which conflicts with a package you have installed. There's probably a newer version of the conflicting package in the repository.

When you tell `apt-get` to install a package, it tries to put your system in a state that includes that package, by making as few changes as possible. Typically this means installing the package and its dependencies; it can also mean removing conflicting packages.

Since you're tracking Debian testing, you should be able to install almost all packages together (this is not true with unstable which is allowed to have unmet dependencies). The easiest way to get on track is often to bring your system up-to-date with `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` before installing new packages.

You could also try using `aptitude` instead of `apt-get`. It's smarter about conflict resolution, so sometimes it'll just do what you want while `apt-get` bombs out; also `aptitude` can let you choose between several ways of resolving a conflict.